# Regex that doesn't allow to write dot(.) right after dot(.)

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I'm a beginner in Qt and C++ programming. I want to use a Regular expression validator in my line edit that doesn't allow to write dot(.) right after dot(.). This is my Regex that I've used :

```
QRegExp reName("[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9. ]+ ")
```

But this is not enough for my task. Please someone help me.

I'm looking for something like this - for example :

- > "camp.new." (accepted)
- > "camp..new" (not accepted)
- > "ca.mp.n.e.w" (accepted)

Comment: If the regular expression is *anchored* when used, it will not match `..` (or any `.`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
^[a-zA-Z](?:\.?[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)+$
```

**Explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

^[a-zA-Z](?:\.?[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)+$

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-zA-Z]                 any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.?                      '.' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z0-9 ]+            any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to
                             'Z', '0' to '9', ' ' (1 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )+                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: May I ask one question more? I've deeply test this regex and I found that it allow to input another symbolic characters like ';:+=-,<> and others. So, how does the regex syntax become if it just allow to input alphabet, number, and dot(.) and also it doesn't allow to input dot(.) right after dot(.)? Please help me again with this one.

Comment: @campnew: Sorry, I don't get you. This regex allows alphanumeric and space and one dot at a time. What do you else?

Comment: the string like "camp:new" or "camp)new" are accepted by regex that you gave. But, I look for the regex that can only accept alphanumeric, space, and one dot at a time. I don't know what's wrong with the regex syntax that I got from u.

Comment: @campnew: Are you using the anchors `^` and  `$`? Perhaps you could edit your question and add some code. It seems to me that you aren't using the regex correctly.

Comment: Yes, I'm using it. I try this app [RegExpPlanner](http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php/RegExp+Planner?content=79791) to figure out what I'm looking for by modifying and test the syntax. But still I can't find the correct one.

This is a couple of my code:
QRegExp reName("^[a-zA-Z](?:.?[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)+$");
QRegExpValidator *namaValid = new QRegExpValidator(reName);
ui->lineEditDNmDebitur->setValidator(namaValid);

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, what you want to do is to say that at each point you've got a `.`, it is not followed by another `.`, and otherwise everything is fine. A negative lookahead assertion is all you need here from the big bag of trickiness, but bear in mind that `.` is an RE metacharacter so there will be some backslashes too.

```
^(?:[^.]|\.(?!\.))*$
```

You might want adjust that further, of course.

In expanded form:

```
^                  # Anchor at start
(?:                # Start sub-RE
   [^.]            #    Not a “.”
|                  #    or...
   \. (?! \. )     #    a “.” if not followed by a “.”
)*                 # As many of the sub-RE as necessary
$                  # Anchor at end
```

---

If you're RE engine anchors things anyway, you can simplify a little:

```
(?:[^.]|\.(?!\.))*
```

Comment: Your code function is to stop adding char when I have input dot(.). But I'm sorry that's not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for regex formula that allow me to write any characters but when I input dot(.) char the regex formula would not allow me to input another dot(.) right after it but I still can continue input another char except dot(.).
For example : 
"camp.new." (accepted)
"camp..new" (not accepted)
"ca.mp.n.e.w" (accepted)

Comment: @campnew Well it all works when I try it with your samples, accepting the ones that should be accepted and rejecting the ones that should be rejected. The **only** thing I don't know is whether you need the anchors. (Also, be aware that you might need to double up the backslashes; the RE needs them to make `.` be non-special.)